Streamlit database access error from snowflake native apps
I have made streamlit under snowflake native apps, and the streamlit is working fine locally, but while going through snowflake native apps, it is not working, like it is not able to use the desired database that I wanted.
Here is the app.py:
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session

def get_snowflake_session() -> Session:
    try:
        # Attempt to get the active session provided by the environment
        session = get_active_session()
        return session
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error getting active Snowflake session: {e}")
        return None

def show_data_page():
    st.title("Snowflake Data Viewer")

    # Ensure credentials are stored in session_state
    if 'user' in st.session_state:
        try:
            session = get_snowflake_session()
            if session:
                st.success("Successfully connected to Snowflake")

                # Display current database and schema
                st.write(f"Database: {st.session_state['database']}")
                st.write(f"Schema: {st.session_state['schema']}")

                # Perform a query to get tables in the specified schema
                query1 = f"""
                    USE DATABASE {st.session_state['database']};
                """
                query2 = f"""
                    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC';
                """
                st.write(f"Executing query: {query1}")
                st.write(f"Executing next query: {query2}")
                try:
                    # Execute the SQL query and retrieve the result directly into a Pandas DataFrame
                    st.write("Database Selection Query")
                    # session.sql(query1)._execute_and_get_query_id()
                    # Convert the result to a Pandas DataFrame
                    st.write("Table Creation:")
                    tables_df = session.sql(query2).to_pandas()
                    st.write("Table:")
                    st.write(tables_df)
                    # tables_df = result.to_pandas()
                    # st.write("Tables in Schema:", tables_df)

                    # Allow the user to select a table and display its contents
                    table_name = st.selectbox("Select a table to view data", tables_df['TABLE_NAME'])
                    if table_name:
                        table_query = f"SELECT * FROM {st.session_state['database']}.{st.session_state['schema']}.{table_name} LIMIT 10"
                        st.write(f"Executing query: {table_query}")

                        table_df = session.sql(table_query).to_pandas()
                        st.write(f"Data in {table_name}:", table_df)
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"Error executing query: {e}")
                    st.write("Debug Info: Could not retrieve table names or table data.")
            session.close()
        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f"Error using Snowflake session: {e}")
    else:
        st.warning("You are not logged in. Please log in first.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Streamlit sidebar inputs for Snowflake credentials
    st.sidebar.header("Snowflake Credentials")
    user = st.sidebar.text_input("User")
    password = st.sidebar.text_input("Password", type="password")
    account = st.sidebar.text_input("Account")
    warehouse = st.sidebar.text_input("Warehouse")
    database = st.sidebar.text_input("Database")
    schema = st.sidebar.text_input("Schema")

    if st.sidebar.button("Connect to Snowflake"):
        if user and password and account and warehouse and database and schema:
            st.session_state['user'] = user
            st.session_state['password'] = password
            st.session_state['account'] = account
            st.session_state['warehouse'] = warehouse
            st.session_state['database'] = database
            st.session_state['schema'] = schema
            show_data_page()
        else:
            st.warning("Please enter all Snowflake credentials")
    else:
        st.warning("Please enter your Snowflake credentials and click the button to connect.")

    # Show data page if connected
    if 'user' in st.session_state:
        show_data_page()


But in this the query part, when I mention a database or the session database it is throwing an error as database not exists or unauthorized, but it is showing snowflake is connected. And the same query is working under snowflake worksheets.
I was trying to do a login with the credentials and accept it and show the tables from the credentials, but it is not working.

Edit: I tried to grant permissions using worksheets and it is working, have given the full details in comments section, but don't know whether it is the permanent or correct solution or not, can someone clarify it?
using this doc


Have you created all the necessary privileges in the manifest.yml file and have you accepted these privileges in the consumer account?

Hi @NickW, thanks for your response. I have applied the privileges in manifest.yml, but how do I accept it in consumer account?

https://other-docs.snowflake.com/en/native-apps/consumer-granting-privs

Yeah I saw this, and have granted all the privileges, but the problem is I'm able to access only two database, one is the application one and the other is the application's package. Maybe because I'm using active session, but I'm not able to create a session when already a session is there, kind of error occurred. So in the active session when I printed the schema and database is wrong, so when I tried to change it using snowflake.yml, it is giving error.

Hi, I don't know whether it is correct or not, but what I did was, I wrote the grant permissions script inside the worksheet, and referred to this doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/preparing-data-content. And have given permissions manually to every schema, and also have migrated the tables from other databases as views and also migrated the data using dbt, and finally was able to access the data. Because, native apps doesn't allow external database access it seems. Don't know if this is the right procedure or not, can someone clarify me!?
